# Highcharts series data array not working

Tags: highcharts

From the servlet I am getting back 3 arrays activeArray,inActiveArray and rejectedArray. I would like to pick these arrays in the java script and come up with a high charts that plots the categories as the blood group names like A+, A- etc. 
The series names will be **Active**, **Inactive** and **rejected**.
The series data will have to be the arrays mentioned above.
I was able to achieve only the categories but the series data does not get plotted. I have included the script code below.

```
<script>
var nameArray ="${nameArray}";


var bloodNames = [
<c:forEach items="${nameArray}" var="name">
    '<c:out value="${name}" />',  
</c:forEach>
];


var  activeValue = new Array();
activeValue = [
<c:forEach items="${activeArray}" var="data">
    '<c:out value="${data}" />',  
</c:forEach>
];


var seriesData = [
    {
        name: 'Active',
        data:activeValue
    },{
        name:'InActive',
        data:[3, 01, 03,0,0,0]
    },
    {
        name:'Rejected',
        data:[4, 01, 03,0,2,0]
    }
]
$(function () { 
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Donar Status Report'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Blood Name Wise'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: 
       bloodNames
    ,
    crosshair: true
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Person (in Counts)'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},
series: seriesData
});
```

});

Comment: I run your code and i don't see any errors. Its working fine. may be your spring MVC (i thing it is.) script is not generating correct values.
check the series Data by alerting (`alert(JSON.stringify(seriesData));`)

Comment: The alert shows up like this [{"name":"Active","data":["1","3","2","2","1","2","0","1","0","0"]},{"name":"InActive","data":[3,1,3,0,0,0]},{"name":"Rejected","data":[4,1,3,0,2,0]}].   But the chart does not display any data for the Active series.

Comment: Suspecting the double quotes in the active data, I did the below changes,                                                                                                                var activeString= JSON.stringify(activeValue);                                               var activeSeriesData= activeString.replace(/\"/g, "");                                           this way the x axis of the chart shows up additional values after the blood names in the x axis like 10,11,12 till 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) function to convert array of string to array of number.Rest of your chart is ok

```js
 var activeValue= ["1","3","2","2","1","2","0","1","0","0"]
 activeValue=activeValue.map(Number)
 console.log(activeValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

The quotes around the data in the active is the problem. The column chart expecting an integer as data.